# Request method 'POST' not supported when use @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using Spring MVC. And get this error: **Request method 'POST' not supported**

Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jdbcInsertGuest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void jdbcInsertGuest(@RequestParam(value = "guestName") String guestName, @RequestParam(value="comment") String comment) {
       Guest guest = new Guest();
       guest.setGuestName(guestName);
       guest.setComment(comment);
       jdbcExample.insertGuest(guest);
}
```

JSP

```
<form name="jdbcInsertGuest" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name: </b></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='guestName'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Comment: </b></td>
                <td><input type='text' name="comment"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

When i change method to GET, i get this error: **Required String parameter 'guestName' is not present**.

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's because post method has a body while get has parameters. Read about get and post and read the spring doc or baeldung tutorials

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the following changes,

1. add the `action="/URL"` attribute into the form, this attribute maps the form event with relevant method from spring mvc controller
2. change the form `name` (jdbcInsertGuest) to guest, this data model pass to the post method
3. use `@ModelAttribute`, this annotation binds form data with relevant model

JSP,

```
<form name="guest" action="/jdbcInsertGuest" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name: </b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestName'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Comment: </b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name="comment"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button>Send</button>
```

MVC controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jdbcInsertGuest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void jdbcInsertGuest(@ModelAttribute("guest") Guest guest) {
    jdbcExample.insertGuest(guest);
}
```

POJO (Guest.java),

```
public class Guest {

    private String guestName;
    private String comment;

    public String getGuestName() {
        return guestName;
    }
    public void setGuestName(String guestName) {
        this.guestName = guestName;
    }
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "action="/jdbcInsertGuest" " in your jsp

```
<form name="jdbcInsertGuest" action="/jdbcInsertGuest" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name: </b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestName'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Comment: </b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name="comment"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button>Send</button>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24725438)

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your answer to add additional information. Don't leave it in the comments.